# How to select predicates and their respective labels in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to list all predicates of an ontology ([NIF](https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies/NIFSTD)) and their labels. When not querying the label, it produces 80 results. So, I assume there are 80 predicates with the term 'nif' in them.

Then I added the line containing `rdfs:label` to the code and it produced no results. So, I wrote the code below to first filter the URI's containing 'nif':

`SELECT DISTINCT ?p ?label 
 WHERE{
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?p), "nif", "i")) .
  ?p rdfs:label ?label .
}
ORDER BY ?p`

But it did not work. I tried using `?p a rdf:Property` instead of the `?s ?p ?o` and that did not work either. I then tried the `Exist` and `Values ?p {"nif"}` but I was unsuccessful with those two too!

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: the query is correct. As I said in my previous comments, be more precise. For example, you loaded which file and expected which predicates to be returned? Nobody here is familiar with all datasets on the web ... the most obvious reason as you said without the `rdfs:label` triple pattern getting results: there are no labels in the dataset that you loaded. Check the files that you loaded. Note, `select ?p {?s ?p ?o}` returns all properties used as predicates of triples, but if there is no other triple `:p rdfs:label "someLabel"` then it can't work. That's an issue in the dataset then

Comment: in all those files here https://github.com/SciCrunch/NIF-Ontology/tree/master/ttl   I can see only classes having labels.

Comment: I have edited the question and mentioned the file. I am using a master file created from all those files in the NIF directory. However, I believe the address I provided contains a similar file since they both have the same size and associated with NIF. When I remove the `FILTER` command, I get labels, however, from different ontologies such as RO and BFO. Can you please write this code using Exists if you have the time?

Comment: Also, should this code return labels then? : `SELECT DISTINCT *{ 
  ?s a rdfs:Class .
  ?s rdfs:label ?label .
}`

Comment: I cannot follow you. When you remove the `FILTER` you get labels, right, because your dataset also imports other external datasets. And those datasets probably do contain labels for properties. Maybe you didn't understand my previous comment(s), but you can only query for data that exists. Open all the imported ontology files, none of them contains labels for the properties of the NIF vocabulary.

Comment: And your last query is not correct, it should be `owl:Class` - but also here, always keep in mind, it will only return those classes that are explicitly declared as type `owl:Class`. And here, the same principle as for the properties, finding all classes used in the instance data, do `select distinct ?cls where {?s a ?cls}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Used vs. declared properties:** In RDF, there is a difference between *using* a predicate and *declaring* a predicate. It is possible to use a predicate without declaring it, and it is possible to declare a predicate without using it.

(It is also possible—and common—to declare a predicate in one file, and use it in a different file. This is how RDF enables re-use of a single ontology in different datasets. There may or may not be an `owl:imports` statement that links the two files.)

To list all predicates *used* in the default graph:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?predicate {
    ?s ?predicate ?o
}
ORDER BY ?predicate
```

To list all predicates *declared* in the default graph, we need to consider which schema language is used to declare it. To list predicates declared with **RDF Schema**:

```
SELECT ?predicate {
    ?predicate a rdf:Property
}
ORDER BY ?predicate
```

To list predicates declared with **OWL**:

```
SELECT ?predicate ?type {
    VALUES ?type { owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty owl:AnnotationProperty }
    ?predicate a ?type
}
ORDER BY ?predicate
```

The query above takes into account that OWL has three different types of predicates: object properties, datatype properties, and annotation properties. So we basically query for each of the three.

With this knowledge, it should be possible to find out what predicates are used in the ontology, and what predicates are declared in the ontology.

**Now, about labels.** The queries above all return the URI—a machine-readable identifier—for the predicates. To also retrieve labels, add `?label` to the list of variables in the `SELECT` clause, and add this to the `WHERE { ... }` block:

```
OPTIONAL { ?predicate rdfs:label ?label }
```

For example:

```
SELECT ?predicate ?label {
    ?predicate a rdf:Property
    OPTIONAL { ?predicate rdfs:label ?label }
}
ORDER BY ?predicate
```

We make the pattern that retrieves the label optional, so if no label is provided in the default graph, the predicate is still returned but without a value for the `?label` variable. This way, one can identify cases where a predicate exists (that is, it is either used or declared) but no label is provided.

If a predicate is declared but no label provided, then I would assume it's a low-quality ontology where insufficient care has been taken in its creation.

If a predicate is used but no label provided, I would not be surprised at all. It might just mean that the declaration and label is provided in a different file, and one needs to find that file and add it to the dataset in order to query labels.

**Constructing labels from the URI:** If the problem is a lack of labels in the ontology, and the labels also cannot be found elsewhere, then here is a version that constructs a best-effort label from the last part of the URI in case no label is declared:

```
OPTIONAL {
    ?predicate rdfs:label ?tmpl
}
BIND (coalesce(?tmpl, replace(replace(replace(str(?predicate), '.*[#/:]', ''), '_', ' '), '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2')) AS ?label)
```

This takes everything after the last hash, slash or colon in the URI, replaces underscores with spaces, and inserts spaces between words in CamelCase notation.

**Lastly, filtering by URI.** Here it is important to be aware that filtering will only happen on the “raw” URI, and not on the prefix-abbreviated form. For example, the following filter accepts only predicates with `rdfs` in the URI:

```
FILTER regex(str(?predicate), 'rdfs', 'i')
```

But it would actually reject `rdfs:label`, `rdfs:comment` and any other properties in the `rdfs` namespace, because their full URIs are of the form

```
<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
```

so the URI actually doesn't contain the string `rdfs`. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you for providing this comprehensive answer! :)

Comment: I had a question: with the code you mentioned regarding `VALUES`, is it possible to only show predicates that include _nif_ in them using this phrase?  `VALUES ?type { owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty owl:AnnotationProperty "nif"}` If not, then why?

Comment: No that wouldn’t work. That would essentially query for `?predicate a "nif"`.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I've read instructions on VALUES, but I had some confusions about it. Now I get it! So, whenever using VALUES, each time one of the variables/ keywords is set as the value for ?type and used in the rest of the code, correct?